# Disable taxonomy field and pick list through jQuery

Tags: jquery, taxonomy

I have a SharePoint 2013 taxonomy field in my site called "Status" and I want to disable it in the new form of the list. Here is what I have done.

```
var controlHondaStatus = getManagedMetadataField("Status");
controlHondaStatus.children().attr("disabled", "disabled");

function getManagedMetadataField(internalName) {
    var field = findFieldByInternalName(internalName);
    field.Control = field.find("div.ms-taxonomy-fieldeditor");
    field.Value = field.Control.find("span.valid-text").text();
    return field;
}
```

But with that implementation the text box of the taxonomy field gets disabled but I can still click the pick list and change the value.
[image]

Is there a way to disable that pick list, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling the image didn't work for me. Replace the image tag with the same markup, so that the OOTB click event handler detached from UI.

```
var imgNode = $(document.getElementById('name_$containercontrolHolder')).children('img.ms-taxonomy-browser-button').eq(0);
    var s = jQuery("<p>").append(imgNode.clone()).html();
    imgNode.replaceWith(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. It works for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
.mr-taxonomy-browser-button{ display:none;
}</style>

and then I use this in my code:

$("#IdOfField1").attr('disabled', true).addClass('mr-taxonomy-browser-button');
```

where `#IdOfField1` is the ID of the taxonomy field.

Comment: <span disabled="disabled" >
  `<span>
     <div>
       <div>
         <img width="15" class="ms-taxonomy-panel-resizer" unselectable="on">`

i have the image like this. now i need to find that image and make it disabled using jquery

Answer (score 0):

//Below is working for both IE and Chrome
//Disable text box of the taxonomy field
$('div[id="name_$containereditableRegion"]').prop("contenteditable", "false").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');

//Disable Managed Meta Data Browse button
  var imgNode = $(document.getElementById('name_$containercontrolHolder')).children('img.ms-taxonomy-browser-button').eq(0);
    var s = jQuery("

").append(imgNode.clone()).html();
    imgNode.replaceWith(s);